How to add an auto increment for every row in Material UI table
I am building a Next.js project by creating a table from Material UI and fetching data from MongoDB. How to manipulate the data from the table?
I want the "#" column with an auto-increment value starting from 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, etc. in every row.
This is my code:
Data models:
{
    appointment: [
      {
        _id: '6609339e8891194adf3beb60',
        name: 'tuyi',
        date: '2024-03-31',
        phone: '45454',
        terapist: 'fdgdf',
        statust: 'done'
      },
    ]
}

page.jsx
async function getAppointment() {
  const res = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/appointment", {
    method: "GET",
    cache: "no-store",
  });
  // const data = await res.json();
  return res.json();
}

async function Appointment() {
  const { appointment } = await getAppointment();

  const columns = [
    { id: "_id", name: "#" },
    { id: "name", name: "Nama" },
    { id: "date", name: "Tanggal" },
    { id: "phone", name: "No Telp." },
    { id: "terapist", name: "Terapis" },
    { id: "statust", name: "Status" },
  ];

  return (

      <TableContainer>
        <Table>
          <TableHead>
            <TableRow>
              {columns.map((column) => (
                <TableCell key={column.id}>{column.name}</TableCell>
              ))}
            </TableRow>
          </TableHead>
          <TableBody>
            {appointment &&
              appointment.map((row, i) => {
                return (
                  <TableRow key={i}>
                    {columns &&
                      columns.map((column, i) => {
                        let value = row[column.id];
                        return <TableCell key={value}>{value}</TableCell>;
                      })}
                  </TableRow>
                );
              })}
          </TableBody>
        </Table>
      </TableContainer>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Appointment;

It turns out like this:


If you want to have an auto incrementing id on database level, I suggest checking out this guide: https://www.mongodb.com/basics/mongodb-auto-increment

In MongoDB the _id will mostly be a hex string that's monotonically increasing. However, since you only want the items to be shown with numeric ID, you can pre-process the data once you completed fetching from the API.
In your case, you can do so after you gotten the JSON from the API:
async function getAppointment() {
  const res = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/appointment", {
    method: "GET",
    cache: "no-store",
  });
  const data = await res.json();
  // Here, you can add a numerically increasing index/ID to all the items
  return { ...data, appointment: data.appointment.map((row, index) => ({ ...row, index: index + 1 }) };
}

// After that, change the following to read from `index` key instead
const columns = [
  { id: "index", name: "#" },
  { id: "name", name: "Nama" },
  { id: "date", name: "Tanggal" },
  { id: "phone", name: "No Telp." },
  { id: "terapist", name: "Terapis" },
  { id: "statust", name: "Status" },
];


Error: data.map is not a function,
looks like i m not calling an array, and turn out the data look like this :
{   appointment: [     {       _id: '66091aa9b2219724bf43f648',       name: 'retert',       date: '2024-04-16',       phone: '27',       terapist: 'ertertret',       createdAt: '2024-03-31T08:11:21.460Z',       updatedAt: '2024-04-19T10:11:59.400Z',       __v: 0,       statust: 'done'     },] }
but when i calling the array no display at all
return data.appointment.map((row, index) => ({ ...row, index: index + 1 });

My apology, I have fixed the issue as I am not aware of the shape of the response @ekopram

ah just solving my problem, i just removing {} from appointment for destructuring assigment, your answer really helping me alot thanks

Either you can modify the data when the response is returned as @AngYC's answer, or you can also customize the displayed value for index by column.id in the template.
Note that you need to change the index variable from the columns array as j to avoid the variable name conflicts with i from the appointment.
{appointment &&
  appointment.map((row, i) => {
    return (
      <TableRow key={i}>
        {columns &&
          columns.map((column, j) => {
            let value = column.id == '_id' ? i + 1 : row[column.id];
            return <TableCell key={value}>{value}</TableCell>;
          })}
      </TableRow>
    );
  })}

I doubt that it is possible to create the React component with async. You will get this error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]).
So you have to work with React hooks: useState and useEffect functions as below:
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

export function Appointment() {
  const [appointment, setAppointment] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      setAppointment((await getAppointment()).appointment);
    }

    fetchData();
  }, []);

  ...

}

Demo @ StackBlitz
